# Open div on element click , close on body OR element click Mootools

Tags: mootools, mootools-events

I made this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nAb6N/10/

As you can see I have 2 animators , a element and body class,
I am adding class to body after the first click on a element but once I click on body is not closing it. If I define animators as

```
 var animators = $$('#opendiv,body');
```

it works ok except that I do not want the div to open on body click. I need it to close on body click.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: your fiddle points to `body.closebox` whereas here you just say `body` above, clearly you are trying things... at the time when you attach, body has no such class and it won't get the event as it won't be returned by the selector. you are _not_ delegating but adding event listeners to available elements. so, are really after clicking outside of the #opendiv to close? - aka, `outerClick` ? or delegating events for conditions met later?

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff well im trying to close the box on "outerClick" as you see , and yes , I see why it does not work on class that is not existed before the click event. any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: do I have to make another on click event for body only?  this is what I am trying to stay away from since my click event is full with morphs for other divs

Comment: theres a different pattern to use, will post it from office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right. Seems as if you really require an outerClick pattern to close. Here's the one that is most notably used within mootools devs, allowing you to create a custom event, based on click:

```
Element.Events.outerClick = {
    base : 'click',
    condition : function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    },
    onAdd : function(fn){
        this.getDocument().addEvent('click', fn);
    },
    onRemove : function(fn){
        this.getDocument().removeEvent('click', fn);
    }
};
```

The way it works is: it is based on a normal `click`. upon adding, it adds the callback as a click event on the document. when a `click` happens within the element itself,it stops bubbling via `event.stopPropagation();`, else, it will bubble and the callback will run.

here's how it ties together after the above:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/nAb6N/13/

```
(function() {
    var opener = $('opendiv');
    var boxtoopen = $('box');

    boxtoopen.set('morph', {
        duration: 700,
        transition: 'bounce:out'
    });

    boxtoopen.addEvent('outerClick', function(event) {
        boxtoopen.morph(".openOff");
        opener.removeClass("hide");
    });

    opener.addEvent('click', function(e) {
        e.stop();
        boxtoopen.morph(".openOn");    
        this.addClass("hide");
    });

})();
```

I have also 'outsourced' the morph properties to the CSS as it makes more sense, semantically.

P.S. note that you need mootools 1.4.3 or 1.4.5, but not 1.4.4 as there's a morph bug to do with units in that release. the jsfiddle above uses 1.4.6 (mootools edge).

Comment: as always our mootools guru Dimitar :)